# Python: get values from list of dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x

I am using [python-sudoers](https://github.com/broadinstitute/python-sudoers) to parse a massive load of sudoers files, alas this library returns some weird data.

looks like a list of dictionaries, i dont really know.

```
[{'run_as': ['ALL'], 'tags': ['NOPASSWD'], 'command': 'TSM_SSI'}, {'run_as': ['ALL'], 'tags': ['NOPASSWD'], 'command': 'SU_TSMWIN'}, {'run_as': ['ALL'], 'tags': ['NOPASSWD'], 'command': 'SU_TSMUNIX'}, {'run_as': ['ALL'], 'tags': ['NOPASSWD'], 'command': 'SU_TSMLIBMGR'}]
```

this works, but i need the single values in variables, like extracted_runas = "ALL", and so on...

```
>>> lst = [{'run_as': ['ALL'], 'tags': ['NOPASSWD'], 'command': 'TSM_SSI'}, {'run_as': ['ALL'], 'tags': ['NOPASSWD'], 'command': 'SU_TSMWIN'}, {'run_as': ['ALL'], 'tags': ['NOPASSWD'], 'command': 'SU_TSMUNIX'}, {'run_as': ['ALL'], 'tags': ['NOPASSWD'], 'command': 'SU_TSMLIBMGR'}]
    >>> print(*[val for dic in lst for val in dic.values()], sep='\n')
['ALL']
['NOPASSWD']
TSM_SSI
['ALL']
['NOPASSWD']
SU_TSMWIN
['ALL']
['NOPASSWD']
SU_TSMUNIX
['ALL']
['NOPASSWD']
SU_TSMLIBMGR
```

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y Problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/174780). 
Please include what problem you are trying to solve here, not how to achieve one detailed bit of a perceived solution. Why do you need to assign each value in the dictionaries to a variable? All you should need is to iterate over the list and access the keys in the each of the dictionaries.

Comment: i'm not going to write out a russian novel about  all the dependent stuff, as this is not of common interest.

Comment: Nobody asked for a Russian novel. Please read [ask] and the the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Providing enough clear and concise context to your question only helps you by letting others give you good answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So because in each dict we have repeated variable names the only possible solution is to name them `extracted_run_as_0 = 'ALL'`, `extracted_run_as_1 = 'ALL'` etc.

```py
for i, dictionary in enumerate(lst):
    for k, v in dictionary.items():
        v = v[0] if isinstance(v, list) else v
        exec(f"extracted_{k}_{i} = {v!r}")

print(extracted_run_as_0, extracted_tags_0, extracted_run_as_1) # etc..
```

Comment: If you need to number the variables, that's a good indication that they should be lists instead. Since the context is reading in an external file, using ``exec`` also runs the risk of executing arbitrary code. When using the current approach, it should at least be ``{v!r}`` instead of ``{v}`` – otherwise, it will convert ``['ALL']`` to looking up the name ``ALL`` instead of just the string ``'ALL'``.

Answer (score -2):

Simple way of iterating dicts:

```
>>> lst = [{'run_as': ['ALL'], 'tags': ['NOPASSWD'], 'command': 'TSM_SSI'}, {'run_as': ['ALL'], 'tags': ['NOPASSWD'], 'command': 'SU_TSMWIN'}, {'run_as': ['ALL'], 'tags': ['NOPASSWD'], 'command': 'SU_TSMUNIX'}, {'run_as': ['ALL'], 'tags': ['NOPASSWD'], 'command': 'SU_TSMLIBMGR'}]
>>> command = [li['command'] for li in lst]
>>> command
['TSM_SSI', 'SU_TSMWIN', 'SU_TSMUNIX', 'SU_TSMLIBMGR']
>>>
```